# Using array in recursion in C++

Tags: c++

Could anyone explain why (numbers + 1) is considered to be an array in this piece of code?

```
int sum(const int numbers[], const int l) {
    return l == 0 ? 0 : numbers[0] + sum(numbers + 1, l-1);
}
```

Comment: It is not considered to be an array (nor is `numbers`)

Answer (score 10):

Whenever you declare the parameter of a function as `f(const int numbers[])`, or, in effect, `f(const int numbers[N])`, it is being decayed to a pointer. In your case, the declaration `f(const int numbers[])` is effectively the same (syntactic sugar) as `f(const int* numbers)`.

However, arrays **ARE NOT THE SAME AS POINTERS** (**REMEMBER THIS!!!!!**). You can pass an array by reference, so the declaration

```
f(int (&numbers)[N]) // numbers is a reference to the array that is passed as a parameter
```

is NOT the same as the declaration

```
f(int* numbers) // even if numbers is an array, it decays to a pointer here
```

In the first case, you can deduce the size of the array via e.g. templates, whereas in the last case there is no way of doing this (assuming you pass an array to `f(int*)`).

Example of array size deduction and why arrays "are more" than pointers in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef> // for std::size_t

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
std::size_t arr_size(T(&)[N]) // pass the array by reference, infer its size
// we don't care about the name, so can just use T(&)[N] instead of T(&numbers)[N]
{
    return N;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[10];
    std::cout << "The size of the array is: " << arr_size(arr); // displays 10
}
```

At the end of the day you have to remember that whenever you have a pointer parameter, you can pass an array to it, it will decay to a pointer. However, arrays are more "evolved", can do more with them, **and are not the same as pointers**. This last point is important, as many (bad) books/teachers tell you that arrays are the same as pointers. **No, they are not the same**.

So, `numbers+1` in your case is just an address, e.g. a pointer, and **not an array**. `numbers` decays to a pointer to `&numbers[0]`, and incrementing 1 makes it a pointer to the second element.

One more example of their differences:

```
#include <iostream>

void g(int (&)[16]){} // reference to array of 16 ints, need EXACTLY the same type (i.e. same dimension also)
void h(int*){} // pointer, arrays will decay to it, regardless of their dimension

int main()
{
    int arr[10];
    // g(arr); // compile time error, arr is not of the same type of `int [16]`
    // works if you declare int arr[16], now you have the same array type
    h(arr); // OK, arr is being decayed to a pointer, dimension doesn't count anymore
}
```

---

**A Gambit of Callables**

Rather than pollute this with another answer, a few things that may be helpful...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

// generic sequence iterators
template<class Iter>
void do_something(Iter beg, Iter end)
{
    for (;beg != end; ++beg)
        std::cout << *beg << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}

// base+length specified overload
template<class T>
void do_something(const T* ar, std::size_t len)
{
    // invoke iterator version
    do_something(ar, std::next(ar,len));
}

// fixed array overload
template<class T, std::size_t N>
void do_something(T (&ar)[N])
{
    // invoke iterator version
    do_something(std::begin(ar), std::end(ar));
}

// sequence container overload
template<class T, template<class,class...> class S, class... Args>
void do_something(const S<T,Args...>& seq)
{
    // invoke iterator version
    do_something(std::begin(seq), std::end(seq));
}


int main()
{
    int ar[10] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };

    do_something(std::begin(ar), std::end(ar)); // iterators
    do_something(ar);                           // fixed array
    do_something(ar+1, 9);                      // base+length specified

    std::vector<long> v(std::begin(ar), std::end(ar));
    do_something(v);                            // sequence container
}
```

**Output**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Enjoy!

Comment: In the first case, "... or use an appropriate constant for `N`". Deduction is certainly a nice advantage of that form, though it is not required. That form also eliminates potential run-time dynamic length, which may not be appropriate for all situations. It is not uncommon to have two overloads; one deducing `N` for `T(&)[N]` as you have it, then forwarding to a second length-provision version that takes `T*, std::size_t`, deducing only `T`.

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks, was just editing :)

Comment: So is (numbers+1) considered to be an array, or not?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner No it is not, numbers+1 is just an address, i.e. a pointer. Added the answer.

Comment: When they're *not* arrays. Pass the same array, but start at index **1** (for whatever reason). How you do it (`numbers+1`, `&numbers[1]`, etc.) I leave to you. A deduced length will not work. You need a pointer + length pairing (as your comment of what `numbers+1` is demonstrates). For maximum flexibility *both* the deduced overload and the address + length options are often provided, with the former simply forwarding to the latter. A *third* way (embraced by modern C++), deduced *iterators*, can also join the fray, and I leave that as an exercise.

Comment: @WhozCraig Can you elaborate a bit on the second one, `T*, std::size_t`? Why would we want to forward to `T*, std::size_t` after deducing both `T` and `N` in `T(&)[N]`?

Comment: @WhozCraig you should really write an answer, will +1 it, I'd really like to see what you mean by *deduced iterators* (are they the same as `std::begin`, `std::end`?)

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks for updating/upgrading the answer, very neat indeed! It will be nice if standard algorithms in `namespace std` (like `std::copy`) will sometime in the future have container overloads, as very often their usage follows the pattern `algoritm(std::begin(Container), std::end(Container), ... )`